# SQL update in ranking order

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Using Oracle 11g, and the data below:

```
create  table ds_tmp
(col1 varchar2(5) ,date1 DATE, col3 varchar2(3));

insert into ds_tmp
values('pat1','01-JAN-2018','PND');

insert into ds_tmp
values('pat1','02-JAN-2018','MIS');

insert into ds_tmp
values('pat1','03-JAN-2018','DUP');

insert into ds_tmp
values('pat2','01-JAN-2017','MIS');

insert into ds_tmp
values('pat2','02-JAN-2017','DUP');

insert into ds_tmp
values('pat2','03-JAN-2017','DUP');

insert into ds_tmp
values('pat2','04-JAN-2017','INV');
```

What I need to do is:
1) group by col1
2) update col3 in the following order:

```
if any col3=PND then set all col3 to PND
else if any col3=MIS set all col3 to MIS
else if any col3=DUP set all col3 to DUP
else set all col3 to INV
```

So, using the data above we would end up with all col3 values for pat1=PND and all col3 values for pat2=MIS. 
I could use CASE to mimic if then else but it only selects on 1 column. I think I may need an an analytic rank function but I can't think how to code it, any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the adjusted value with:

```
select col1, date1, col3,
  case
    when count(case when col3 = 'PND' then col3 end)
           over (partition by col1) > 0 then 'PND'
    when count(case when col3 = 'MIS' then col3 end)
           over (partition by col1) > 0 then 'MIS'
    when count(case when col3 = 'DUP' then col3 end)
           over (partition by col1) > 0 then 'DUP'
  end as adj_col3
from ds_tmp;

COL1  DATE1       COL ADJ
----- ----------- --- ---
pat1  03-JAN-2018 DUP PND
pat1  02-JAN-2018 MIS PND
pat1  01-JAN-2018 PND PND
pat2  03-JAN-2017 DUP MIS
pat2  02-JAN-2017 DUP MIS
pat2  04-JAN-2017 INV MIS
pat2  01-JAN-2017 MIS MIS
```

Then either replace `col3` with that expression in your query, or use it for an update if you actually want to change the values in the table.

The `over (partition by col1)` does the 'grouping' part, and the three values are evaluated in the order you wanted, so PND takes priority over MIS etc.

Comment: Well, that was quick. I thought it was some combination of case and partitiion over, I didn't realise you could combine the 2. Thanks for your help